# Is IBIS2 the same exchange as AEB in Interactive Brokers?

Tags: etf, european-union, interactive-brokers

I am trying to buy some [SPDR MSCI World UCITS ETF](https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?isin=IE00BFY0GT14&from=search) in Interactive Brokers. Its ISIN is IE00BFY0GT14.

When I search this ISIN in Interactive Brokers, I see in the search results that I can buy it from the [Euronext NL Stocks (AEB)](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2222&exch=aeb&showcategories=) exchange:

[image]

But when I pick the SPPW STK@AEB from the search result, it shows me that the exchange is IBIS2 now, not AEB:

[image]

That looks confusing. Is IBIS2 the same exchange as AEB? From [this Interacribe Brokers answer](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/lib/cstools/faq/#/content/41556429), it looks like they are actually different.

Answer (score 1):

No, IBIS2 is the IBKR code for Xetra, the leading exchange in Germany.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know why does IBKR open IBIS2 exchange when I select SPPW STK@AEB? As if for IBKR there is no difference between AEB and IBIS2.

Comment: @yaskovdev No idea :D